# How to make a J2ME application run in Background?

Tags: java, java-me, midlet, midp

I have a written a J2ME application which uses Bluetooth and search a file within the peer mobile and download it. I would like to make my application run in background , whenever I get a call , or message and later resume after few seconds , Has anybody worked on this please share your experience . Is there any way to run a Midlet in background ?

Comment: there is already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084384/how-do-i-minimize-a-j2me-app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to set a j2me app to the background use the following in your midlet class:

```
          Display.getDisplay (this).setCurrent (null);
```

to get the screen back use the following:

```
          Display.getDisplay (this).setCurrent (myCanvas);
```

Where myCanvas is your canvas instantiation

R

p.s. You can still use a thread or timer to do things in the background while your midlet is hidden.

p.s.2: this does not work on all models. (Works on Nokia s60, SonyEricsson, but not on Nokia s40, Samsung and some others.

Answer (score 2):

A device's ability to run an application in the background depends on its ability to multitask. Therefore, more expensive, PDA-type devices are more likely to support background execution than lower-cost devices.
For in background :-

```
private Display display = Display.getDisplay(this);
private Displayable previousDisplayable;

public void toBack() {
previousDisplayable = display.getCurrent();
display.setCurrent(null);
}
```

And to come in Fore ground :-

```
public void toFront() {
display.setCurrent(previousDisplayable);
}
```

But be aware that it not supports every device.(Works on Nokia s60, SonyEricsson, but not on Nokia s40, Samsung and some others).