# j2me multitasking

Tags: java-me

Is it possible to run an application in background and user can use the mobile simply and can do the common task in j2me ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know...

It depends on the mobile for which you are developing the app. If you are developing for a mobile OS like Symbian S60 **which supports multitasking** then it is auto-handled by it.

---

***Edit***

To know how to minimize a J2ME app to run in the background see the following threads:

1. [How to make a J2ME application run in Background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157483/how-to-make-a-j2me-application-run-in-background)
2. [How Do I Minimize a J2ME App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084384/how-do-i-minimize-a-j2me-app)

Comment: Thanks a lot .You me I can not develop an general mobile application which can go in background..

Comment: @ranjeet: I haven't said that. See my edit in answer. Links will help you.